# c++ - does std::is_convertible checks if temporary is created?

Tags: c++, std, implicit-conversion

I've been examining [this paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) on the origins of `std::forward`, and the author (in exemplifying the last, 5th implementation of the one) wrote the following:

> It allows any conversion in which a temporary is not created as a
> result of the conversion.

This implementation of `std::forward` uses `std::is_convertible` to check if `U` is convertible to`T` (it is 2009th discussion of old implementations of `std::forward`).

In [this description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) of `std::is_convertible` I read the following:

> `std::declval<From>()` can be converted to To using implicit
> conversions

But as I may understand, temporary *can* be created during implicit conversion, say via user-defined conversion sequence, or even if `int` is converted to `float`.

Could you point we where I am wrong in this line of reasoning, because clearly the author of the paper did know what he wrote about.

Comment: Having only briefly skimmed through the paper, this is just the first impression: pay special attention what `std::is_convertible` is getting applied to -- not to the types in question, but to ***pointers*** to those types.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is a keen observation! This makes so much sense now, thank you for noticing that!